# How did the Joker survive the helicopter crash?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

How did the Joker survive the helicopter crash in *Suicide Squad* after he pushed Harley Quinn out of the helicopter? The crash seemed impossible to survive from.

Comment: Deus ex Machina. How do character's get in a head on collision and get out and walk away? etc. Movies don't always make sense.

Comment: @sanpaco yeah, that's what I thought too but I was wondering if there was an explanation (or maybe from the comic books)

Comment: I think he ma have jumped out be for the crash. I think that because he didn't really die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One theory that's been floated in various circles on the internet, but neither confirmed nor denied by the makers of the movie, is that Joker's survival might have been the result of Harley Quinn's deal with Enchantress (script lifted from [here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=suicide-squad)).

> **HARLEY**: Hey lady? I lost my Puddin'. But you can get him back, right?
>   **ENCHANTRESS**: I can, my dear. Anything you want.
>   **HARLEY**: You promise?
>   **ENCHANTRESS**: Yes, child. You need only Bow ... and serve beneath my feet.

Of course, shortly after that, Harley betrays Enchantress, but there's a chance that Enchantress had already fulfilled her part of the deal, restoring Joker to life.

Comment: If she had brought him back, it likely would have been as a zombie though

Comment: ^_^ Very "Monkey's Paw".

Answer (score 8):

Same way Amanda Waller survived her equally deadly crash. Luck and plot armor and a side of too stubborn to die.

The specifics are not explained in any media at this time.

Answer (score 4):

Or the helicopter crashed into a building, the front exploded, but the back was wedged in the building and undamaged, so the joker survived, albeit with a burnt face, as seen in the deleted scene.

Answer (score 2):

During the helicopter crash scene when Harley Quinn falls on the building, the scene remains there and we see Harley Quinn's somersault for a few seconds and then switch back to the crashing helicopter.

Maybe during that time Joker also jumped from the helicopter to some safe place before the helicopter crashed. And rememberer that Joker is a famous escape artist and great surviver in the comics too.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility that nobody mentioned yet is that the Joker planned all along to stage his own death.

This can explain why he pushed Harley Quinn out, [on purpose](https://screenrant.com/suicide-squad-joker-harley-quinn-helicopter-scene-explained/):

[image: twitter confirms pushing Quinn on purpose]

I think it was in order for him to be able to stage his death, without Quinn interrupting, while knowing she'll survive, as it was right above a building.